# AngularJS access route resolve result within another resolve

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following route resolve:

```
resolve: {
      user: function($route, User){
        return User.find($route.current.params.id);
      },
      stats: function($route, Stats) {
        /* return async stats based on the 'user' object I retrieved in the function above this one*/
        var user = ... from previous function ...
        return Stats.load(user.email);
      }
}
```

How can I access the returned user from the 'user' function inside the 'stats' function? I'd like to avoid running this logic inside the controller and keep it within the resolve.

Thanks!

Comment: Why can't you use the same `$route.current.params.id` from the `user` resolve?

Comment: Well I guess it's a bad example. I'll change it to email for example's sake

Comment: Ok, what if you use just one `resolve`? Like `userStatus: function($route, User, Stats) {  }`

Comment: But I'd like to have both parameters accessible within the controller, separated. Sure, I could get fancy and return an object with two keys, but not really interested..

Answer (score 0):

Guess **[this](https://plnkr.co/edit/G2Sq2Asa7cIoMKUh2x5G?p=preview)** is what you want.

You can access the values returned by all the `resolve` using a promise (`$q`) or `$timeout`.